# regex or statement in any order

Tags: python, regex

Python regular expression I have a string that contains keywords but sometimes the keywords dont exist and they are not in any particular oder. I need help with the regular expression.

Keywords are:

```
Up-to-date
date added
date trained
```

These are the keywords i need to find amongst a number of other keywords and they may not exist and will be in any order.

What the sting looks like

```
<div>
<h2 class='someClass'>text</h2>

 blah blah blah Up-to-date blah date added blah

</div>
```

what i've tried:

```
regex = re.compile('</h2>.*(Up\-to\-date|date\sadded|date\strained)*.*</div>') 

regex = re.compile('</h2>.*(Up\-to\-date?)|(date\sadded?)|(date\strained?).*</div>')

re.findall(regex,string)
```

The outcome i'm looking for would be:

```
If all exists
['Up-to-date','date added','date trained']

If some exists
['Up-to-date','','date trained']
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the </h2> and </div> strings?  Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: im searching for keywords within the paramaters of an ending h2 tag and the ending of a div tag

Comment: yeah... my delimiters are not , or ' or "" im searching for text not in any particular order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a regex? If not, you could use `find`:

```
In [12]: sentence = 'hello world cat dog'

In [13]: words = ['cat', 'bear', 'dog']

In [15]: [w*(sentence.find(w)>=0) for w in words]
Out[15]: ['cat', '', 'dog']
```

Comment: what if the keyword is keyword: variable and i know the keyword but the variable is, well a variable

Comment: Indeed, you begin to enter regex territory. I'm no regex expert, but maybe `re.compile('dog:[A-Za-z0-9]*')`?

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want, but it smells:

```
import re

def check(the_str):
    output_list = []
    u2d = re.compile('</h2>.*Up\-to\-date*.*</div>') 
    da = re.compile('</h2>.*date\sadded*.*</div>')
    dt = re.compile('</h2>.*date\strained*.*</div>')
    if re.match(u2d, the_str):
        output_list.append("Up-to-date")
    if re.match(da, the_str):
        output_list.append("date added")
    if re.match(dt, the_str):
        output_list.append("date trained")

    return output_list

the_str = "</h2>My super cool string with the date added and then some more text</div>"
print check(the_str)
the_str2 = "</h2>My super cool string date added with the date trained and then some more text</div>"
print check(the_str2)
the_str3 = "</h2>My super cool string date added with the date trained and then Up-to-date some more text</div>"
print check(the_str3)
```